# How to address an invalid "NOT IN ()" query?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sql

## Symptoms:

In WordPress admin menu we cannot see any pages or products listed any more,
even thoguh the pages and products are still accessible through weblinks for example.

## Tracing the issue:

On one hand as far as I can see in query monitor is that an invalid empty array parameter is provided for **NOT IN()**:

 "`AND wp_posts.post_author NOT IN ()`"
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax`
The caller line is long, seemingly it originates somewhere in WooCommerce or WooCommerce-payments plugins.
Unfortunately the problem does not go away if I disable such plugins (and most others also).

 The problem however DOES go away if I disable the i-excel THEME.

 Obviously I need the theme to be turned back on.

 it had no issues this far, and we did not update anything in the system really.
So I'm stuck in here.

### Updates 2:

I have traced down everything in the callstack.
up until "`get_option('wp_custom_filters');`"
I want to know what is/what is inside`wp_custom_filters`
to see if that can be amended on the user interface/database level maybe. I did not find anything about it in google yet.

```
function customFiltersSettings() {
    $settings = get_option('wp_custom_filters');

    if (!$settings) {
        return null;
    }

    return unserialize(base64_decode($settings));
}
```

There is a criterium for sending null if the list is empty,
and `wp_posts.post_author NOT IN (null)` would create no error,
but for some reason `wp_posts.post_author NOT IN ()` runs instead at the end.

## Appendix

This is the shortest query error out of the 4 thta I can see in query monitor:

```js
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_subscription'
AND wp_posts.post_author NOT IN ()
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

The caller for that shows this:

```js
WP_Query->get_posts()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3219
WP_Query->query()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3800
WP_Query->__construct()
wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3932
WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT->query()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-order-data-store-cpt.php:965
WC_Data_Store->__call()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-data-store.php:207
WC_Order_Query->get_orders()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-query.php:87
wc_get_orders()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-order-functions.php:66
wcs_do_subscriptions_exist()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/wcs-functions.php:62
WC_Payments_Subscriptions_Empty_State_Manager->replace_subscriptions_empty_state()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/includes/subscriptions/class-wc-payments-subscriptions-empty-state-manager.php:93
apply_filters('woocommerce_subscriptions_not_found_label')
wp-includes/plugin.php:205
WC_Subscriptions_Core_Plugin->register_order_types()
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-payments/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-core-plugin.php:341
do_action('init')
wp-includes/plugin.php:517
```

Comment: One furthe UPDATE: It seems that unfortuunately WordPress auto-updated itself recently to the latest release. That at least explains where the change comes from. What can be the next best steps knowing that?  Maybe rolling back to a backup and trying to turn aouto-updat off somehow?

Comment: You'll need to check with the theme's support team about this. Third-party theme support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it eventually.
I suspect this was an injection attack on the system by a bot that managed to create a user account for itself.
One lesson learned is to govern user creation more strictly. 
But it's still not fully clear what/how the intruder acted, 
so if somebody has a clue, share in the comments please...

This is what I conlcluded and mitigated:
In the `AND wp_posts.post_author NOT IN ()`, the `()` was receiving it's value from:

```
function customFiltersSettings() {
    $settings = get_option('wp_custom_filters');

    if (!$settings) {
        return null;
    }

    return unserialize(base64_decode($settings));
}
```

I looked up the database's wp_options table to see what the `wp_custom_filters` entry contains,
 and it contained 'YTowOnt9' a.k.a `a:0:{}` translated from base64. 
This way the `!$settings` protection could not replace the empty array with a suitable `null`, 
because at the time of checking it was a real value in base64.
**So simply deleting the content of `wp_custom_filters` entry in the `wp_options` table of the database, resolved the error.**

Theme/Plugin/WPDevelopers need to check, but I think this might be a live vulnerability in i-excel and also in twentytwenty theme I think. (maybe even more).

I would suggest a correction that would expand the `if !$settings` part with some extra code that also validates the decoded value of `unserialize(base64_decode($settings)` ...
What I don't know among many things yet is what wp_custom_filters originates from, and how can somebody from the UI modify it's content?! (eg. where was the intrusion point, AND where can I use this option for something actually useful.